# Can we specify the author name while generating the changelog file in liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

I have generated a changelog file of a database using liquibase. In the changelog file the author name is set automatically. Is there a way of specifying the author name while generating the changelog file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing from command line you can use -Duser.name param:

`mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog -Duser.name=YOURUSERNAME`

Answer (score 0):

Not currently available, but it should be fairly simple to implement. Until it is implemented, you could use something like `sed` or an XSLT transform to post-process it.

Comment: can you give an example??

Comment: I have no idea of these things but want to learn them. So if you can just help me out.

Comment: No I am just asking can you give any reference from where I can learn about it . I am not asking you to give the whole thing.

Comment: Is there any other way of changing the author while generation of the changelog file itself?

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase uses the user name using the user.name system property.
You can export the JAVA_OPTS environment variable

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.name=dhalder
```

This should create changelog with author tag having value dhalder.

Comment: My system doesn't have the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. WHat should I do??

Comment: Depending on the OS you are using , there are various ways you can add it.Which OS are you using ? What is your preferred way of running liquibase?

Comment: I am using windows 7. Installed liquibase in drive E. Run it through command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing from command line the liquibase.bat (windows) or liquibase (git-bash) found in the installation directory eg. C:\Program Files\liquibase (default) then you can try

```
./liquibase [other options] --changeSetAuthor="ABCD" [command]
```